# adding swipe support for Lightbox2?

Tags: swipe, lightbox2

I use Lightbox2 on my website, I found it to be the best gallery according to my taste but there is one problem remaining : I hate not having the swipe support for mobile devices... this is frustrating for users.

Does anybody knows how to add swipe gesture support to Lightbox2 plugin?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I use Hammer.js library to perform the swipe functions.
First add Hammer library to your site: [hammerjs on github](http://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js)
Secondly add the jquery.hammer.js function to your site. Github location: [Github](https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js)

At last add the jquery scrip code to your site:

```
$('#lightbox').hammer().on("swipe", function (event) {
                if (event.gesture.direction === 4) {
                    $('#lightbox a.lb-prev').trigger('click');
                } else if (event.gesture.direction === 2) {
                    $('#lightbox a.lb-next').trigger('click');
                }
            });
```

Comment: Where do you put this code? The div #lightbox is not existent when loading the window. It is created when opening the lightbox...